# ASP.NET reading files from BIN

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I am processing some CSV file which i have copied in Bin folder of My ASP.NET Website.

When i execute

```
using (IDataReader csv = new CsvReader
               (new StreamReader("sample.txt"), true, '|'))
{
 .....
}
```

it complains me that `"sample.txt"` not found in "`c:\Program Files\.....\`"

Won't the `runtime` automatically look into the `bin` folder?
what modification do i need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a full path by calling `Server.MapPath`:

```
new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(@"~/bin/sample.txt"))
```

However, you should not put anything in the `bin` folder other than assemblies.
You should use the `App_Data` folder instead.